# Zend framework paginator distinct

Tags: php, zend-framework

If I have a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(test) AS "test" FROM table ORDER BY "onderwerp" ASC LIMIT 10
```

The amount of pages is never right as it will add another query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS "zend_paginator_row_count" FROM table
```

What is the best way to get the right amount of pages with a distinct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html (the The DbSelect and DbTableSelect adapter section), you can specify the query to use to get the count.

`$adapter->setRowCount(<a new query to get just the count>);`